# Basic Java decoder program not passing correct values?

Tags: java, string, variables, char

I have a program that is supposed to read in a series of strings subtract a numeric key from their ascii value and print out the decoded words. There is an issue in my logic somewhere. Any thoughts?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MsgDecoder
{
public static void main(String[] args)
throws Exception 
{
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File("data5b.txt"));
    String word, temp, newMsg = "";
    word = input1.next();
    while(input1.hasNext())
    {
        temp = decoder(input1, word);
        newMsg = newMsg + " " + temp;
        word = input1.next();
    }
    System.out.println(newMsg);
}

static String decoder(Scanner in, String w)
throws Exception
{
    String temp = "";
    char c; 
    int key;
    Scanner altInput = new Scanner(new File("data5a.txt"));
    key = altInput.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++)
    {
        c = w.charAt(i);
        c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        if(c > 96 && c < 123)
        {
            c = (char)(c - key);
        }
        temp = temp + "" + Character.toString(c);
    }
    return temp;
}
}
```

and here are the two data files

```
data5a.txt
9

data5b.txt
Xwuh cqn vnmrxlan jan jufjhb jc cqnra knbc
Cqn zdrlt kaxfw oxg sdvynm xena cqn ujih mxp
Anjurch rb cqn vdamna xo j knjdcrodu cqnxah kh j pjwp xo dpuh ojlcb
Fqx hxd pxwwj cx ljuu, pqxbckdbcnab
Cx naa rb qdvjw, kdc cx anjuuh oxdu cqrwpb dy anzdranb j lxvydcna
Cx kn xa Wxc cx kn cqjc rb cqn zdnbcrxw
Adunb jan vjmn oxa cqn pdrmjwln xo frbn vnw jwm cqn xknmrnwln xo oxxub
Hxd ljw wnena dwmnanbcrvjcn cqn bcdyrmrch xo cqn pnwnaju ydkurl
Cqxbn fqx frbq cx jyynja frbn jvxwp oxxub, jvxwp cqn frbn bnnv oxxurbq
stop
```

Comment: How does your "issue" manifest?  What misbehavior or error do you observe?

Comment: It outputs: onl_ Zhe mediocXe aXe al]a_Y aZ ZheiX beYZ Zhe q[ick bXo]n fo^ j[mped o\eX Zhe la`_ dog XealiZ_ iY Zhe m[XdeX of a bea[Zif[l ZheoX_ b_ a gang of [gl_ facZY ]ho _o[ gonna Zo call, ghoYZb[YZeXY Zo eXX iY h[man, b[Z Zo Xeall_ fo[l ZhingY [p Xeq[iXeY a comp[ZeX Zo be oX noZ Zo be ZhaZ iY Zhe q[eYZion X[leY aXe made foX Zhe g[idance of ]iYe men and Zhe obedience of foolY _o[ can ne\eX [ndeXeYZimaZe Zhe YZ[pidiZ_ of Zhe geneXal p[blic ZhoYe ]ho ]iYh Zo appeaX ]iYe among foolY, among Zhe ]iYe Yeem fooliYh

Comment: Are you also encoding that String?

Comment: May I ask: why `if(c > 96 && c < 123)`? Why not `if(c > ('a' + key) && c < ('z' + key))`? (Its a lot simpler too)

Comment: @ambigram_maker And wrong. Because the encoder doesn't limit the input that way.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Hmm... fair point. So we could do without it(?)

Comment: Tell us what you intended it to print. (So that the difference is apparent)

Comment: I do not have the ouput for this input, but I do have an example input that does not work either. One second, I will post it and its output.

Comment: *znk waoiq hxuct lud pasvkj ubkx znk rgfe jum*
decoded is - *the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog*
when the key = 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first line of the input i got this to output this:

```
only the mediocre are always at their best
```

after your

```
c = (char)(c - key);
```

you need to check to see if it is still in range of 97 to 122
so i added an if then statment

```
if(!(c > 96)){
    c = (char) (c + 26) ; 
}
```

so your whole code loop looks like this now

```
for(int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++){
    c = w.charAt(i);
    c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
    if(c > 96 && c < 123){
        c = (char)(c - key);
        if(!(c > 96)){
            c = (char) (c + 26) ;
        }
    }
    temp = temp + "" + Character.toString(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a few minor issues.

The main one appears to be that this ...

```
            c = (char)(c - key);
```

... does not wrap around, so input characters from 'a' to 'i' (for key 9) will be converted to characters outside the range 'a' - 'z'.  You probably want something more like this:

```
            c = (char) ((((c - 'a') + 26 - key) % 26) + 'a');
```

You also have a bit of an issue here:

```
    word = input1.next();
    while(input1.hasNext())
    {
        temp = decoder(input1, word);
        newMsg = newMsg + " " + temp;
        word = input1.next();
   }
```

You should be testing first whether there is a token, then reading it, but you are doing it the other way around.

Also, you read the (same) key again and again, each time you invoke `decode()`.  That's not wrong, exactly, but it sure would be more efficient to read the key just once, and pass it to `decode()` as an argument.

Oh, and you never use the first argument to `decode()`.

Comment: Elliott Frisch 's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27043107/2959259) gives a much simpler solution to the *modulo 26* issue: `ch = 26 - key + ch`.

Comment: @ambigram_maker not so.  The line you quoted is not a complete solution.  The whole solution in the answer you cite is seven lines long, and completely equivalent to my one-liner.  One might prefer the seven-line version on other grounds, but it is not any simpler.

Comment: Pardon me... I am such an idiot that I an incapable of evaluating multi-level parenthesized expressions, which make me praise the caliber of the person providing the logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `decoder` should look something like (using a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to clean-up),

```
static String decoder(String w) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (Scanner altInput = new Scanner(new File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), "data5a.txt"));) {
        int key = altInput.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
            int ch = Character.toLowerCase(w.charAt(i)) - 'a';
            if (ch >= key) {
                ch -= key;
            } else {
                ch = 26 - key + ch;
            }
            ch += 'a';
            sb.append((char) ch);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Output with your files is

> only the mediocre are always at their best the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog reality is the murder of a beautiful theory by a gang of ugly facts who you gonna to call= ghostbusters to err is human= but to really foul things up requires a computer to be or not to be that is the question rules are made for the guidance of wise men and the obedience of fools you can never underestimate the stupidity of the general public those who wish to appear wise among fools= among the wise seem foolish

Comment: FYI your code it taking in everything and changing it. where the user code it only accepting chars that is within the lowercase letters and subtracting it. that is why u got = symbols instead of ,

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = decode(9,
        "Xwuh cqn vnmrxlan jan jufjhb jc cqnra knbc\n" +
        "Cqn zdrlt kaxfw oxg sdvynm xena cqn ujih mxp\n" +
        "Anjurch rb cqn vdamna xo j knjdcrodu cqnxah kh j pjwp xo dpuh ojlcb\n" +
        "Fqx hxd pxwwj cx ljuu, pqxbckdbcnab\n" +
        "Cx naa rb qdvjw, kdc cx anjuuh oxdu cqrwpb dy anzdranb j lxvydcna\n" +
        "Cx kn xa Wxc cx kn cqjc rb cqn zdnbcrxw\n" +
        "Adunb jan vjmn oxa cqn pdrmjwln xo frbn vnw jwm cqn xknmrnwln xo oxxub\n" +
        "Hxd ljw wnena dwmnanbcrvjcn cqn bcdyrmrch xo cqn pnwnaju ydkurl\n" +
        "Cqxbn fqx frbq cx jyynja frbn jvxwp oxxub, jvxwp cqn frbn bnnv oxxurbq\n");

String decode(int key, String text) {
    char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
        char ch = chars[i];
        if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') {
            ch = (char) ('a' + (((int)ch - 'a' + 26 - key) % 26));
        } else if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') {
            ch = (char) ('A' + (((int)ch - 'A' + 26 - key) % 26));
        }
        chars[i] = ch;
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

I think there is need of a wrap-around (modulo 26).